# Examples for 2-dimensional real valued harmonic functions

Tags: harmonic-functions

Given:
$$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R},\space \Delta{f}=0, \space\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x}^2_i} \neq 0, i \in\{1,2 \}.$$
Are there examples of such functions?

Comment: You mean something like $f(x,y) = x^2-y^2$?

Comment: $f(x,y)=e^xsin(y)$ also works fine

and yes, Old John's example is Harmonic since the definition only requires that $\Delta f=0$

Comment: @OldJohn It's harmonic after you edited the comment :)

Comment: Ah yes - I thought I had fixed the typo quickly enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to prevent this question reappearing in the unsolved list:

The simplest example I can think of would be $f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$.

That this is harmonic can be seen by either calculating $\Delta{f}$ and finding that is identically zero, or simply by noticing that this function is the real part of the holomorphic function $f(z) = z^2$.

When you state the condition $\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x}^2_i} \neq 0$, it might not be 100% clear whether you meant "is not identically zero" or "is never zero", but this particular example does both, since $\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x}^2} = 2$ everywhere.